# Get DHCP IP-Address range

Tags: java, networking, ip-address, dhcp

I want to search the local network for special servers to communicate with. To achieve this I'm running a for-loop pinging all IP-Addresses in the range I give the function.

E.g. `findServers("192.168.0.x", 101, 255)` pings all addresses between `192.168.0.101` and `192.168.0.255` and, if they are reachable, tries to connect to a specific port to find out whether a server is running.

But I don't want to enter the range manually. Is there any way to get the IP-range in which the DHCP-server assigns addresses to the machines in the network?

Comment: Subnet mask won't help here. The DHCP dynamic address range doesn't have to be a proper subnet of the network's subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the subnet for your machine and try to connect to the port in question. This saves you needing to know the specific address range the DHCP will give out.

You don't need to determine if the host is reachable because you would still have to attempt to connect to the port.  If you connect to 255 addresses using a thread pool it will take a few seconds.

Instead of using TCP you could use UDP.  UDP can send a broad cast to a whole subnet or multi-cast across networks with a single packet.  This would allow you to send a request to any number of machines to find out if they have a service available.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to obtain this would be to ask the administrator of the DHCP server. One remote possibility is if the DHCP server exposed an SNMP server as well and that SNMP server provided the information.  However, no sysadmin worth his/her salt would expose that information, so it's unlikely.

In short, the answer is about 99.9% likely to be "you can't".

Comment: The DHCP is a router I am administrating... But I want it be be usable  in other networks too

Comment: The answer still stands. There is no standard API that you can expect to be generally available for querying a DHCP server's dynamic range.  In limited specific cases you might be able to use SNMP.  If you control ALL the DHCP servers for which you want to do this you could set up an SNMP server on each DHCP machine and publish the information.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but maybe someone Google it. You can get it with PowerShell:

```
$dhcpserver = "10.17.5.1"
$ScopeList = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $dhcpserver | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*toip*"}

ForEach($Scope in $ScopeList){

    $voip += Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $dhcpserver -ScopeId $Scope.ScopeId

}
```

**This will only work** if the scopes for Voips have a pattern like "toip".

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell doing it remotely:

```
$DHCPServer="<name or IP address of DHCP Server>"
$Cred=Get-Credential -Message "Input credentials" -UserName "<username>"
$CimSession=New-CimSession -ComputerName $DHCPServer -Credential $Cred
$Scopes=Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DHCPServer -CimSession $CimSession
Remove-CimSession -CimSession $CimSession
$Scopes | Select-Object -Property ScopeId,Name,Description,StartRange,EndRange
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such protocol that propagates the available ip address range, provided by the DHCP server.